# Attribute @click is not serializable as XML 1.0., and other Errors

Tags: class, click, serializable, v-for, v-model

I'm principiant in coding and i'm trying to do a simple App using Vue.js. Everything seems to function but the check in "Nu Html Checker" has discovered several errors, like :"Attribute @click is not serializable as XML 1.0.", "Attribute v-for not allowed on element li at this point.", "Attribute :class not allowed on element li at this point.".

I have tried several things but nothing seems to work. Many thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>To Do List</title>
    <script src="lib/js/vue.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/formating.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="buerokramApp">
        <h1>To Do List</h1>
        <p> <label for="newTask">Neue Aufgaben</label> <input type="text" id="newTask" v-model="newTask"> <button class="nsrt" @click="nsrtTask">Insert</button> </p>
        <h2>Alle Aufgaben</h2>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="(task, index) in tasks" :class="{'terminated' :task.fertig}">
                <p>{{task.name}}</p> <button class="doneChanged" @click="doneChanged(index)">&#10004; </button> <button class="putAway" @click="putAway(index)">&#10005; </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <h2>In Bearbeitung</h2>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="task in bearbeitung">{{task.name}}</li>
        </ul>
        <h2>Erledigt</h2>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="task in erledigt">{{task.name}} <button class="agacan" type="button" name="button">&#9993; </button> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        var app = new Vue({
        
          el: "#buerokramApp",
          data: {
            tasks: [
              {name: "In Büro kommen", fertig: true},
              {name: "Korrespondez lessen", fertig: false},
              {name: "Morgenkreis", fertig: false},
              {name: "Strafverfahren Nr.123 bearbeiten", fertig: false},
              {name: "Termin in Landgericht", fertig: false},
              {name: "Delegation abholen im Flughafen", fertig: false},
            ],
            newTask: ''
          },
          computed:{
            erledigt(){
              return this.tasks.filter(task => task.fertig);
            },
            bearbeitung(){
              return this.tasks.filter(task => !task.fertig);
            },
          },
          methods:{
            nsrtTask(){
              this.tasks.push({name: this.newTask, fertig: false});
              this.newTask= '';
            },
            putAway(index){
              this.tasks.splice(index, 1);
            },
            doneChanged(index){
              this.tasks[index].fertig = !this.tasks[index].fertig;
            }
          }
        });
        
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```